# Change lowercase characters by uppercase characters for some files using a script in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to modify all the files in a directory by changing all the lowercase characters to uppercase characters with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in "/home/user/*"
do
   tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < "$file" > "$file"
done
```

But with that script, all the content in the files is erased and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use the same file as both input and output.**

You could use a temporary file to store `tr`'s output, and then `mv` it back, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in "/home/user/*"
do
    tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < "$file" > tmp_file
    mv tmp_file "$file"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how tr works:

```
[blah@exchange ~]# echo "SOMEthing" | tr abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
SOMETHING
```

So you can do:

```
cat input-file.txt | tr abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ > output-file.txt
```

or

```
cat $file | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' > tmp.txt && mv -f tmp.txt $file
```